# Why am I getting low transformation efficiency with DB3.1 E.coli cells?

Tags: molecular-biology, competent-cells

I am making competent cells using DB3.1 *E. coli* cells. Even after following the exact protocol (Inoue method for ultracompetent cells) given in 'Sambrook and Russel', I am not getting transformation efficiency of more than 10<sup>4</sup>. I am using a 5.1kb plasmid for checking transformation efficiency.

I will be thankful if any of you can share your experience in this experiment.

Answer (score 1):

How are you storing the cells?  Competent cells can be very finicky.  In my lab, we usually flash-freeze them with ethanol/dry-ice and store at -81 degrees (long-term use) or we store them surrounded by ice at 4 degrees (short-term use).